# How can I disable the login for users in CKAN?

Tags: ckan

I want to be able for a while to disable users from logging into the website using a web browser. They should all be logged out and the form for logging in should disappear from the website.

Answer (score 0):

CKAN has a `who.ini` [file](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/config/who.ini) that contains the following section:

```
[identifiers]
plugins =
    friendlyform;browser
    auth_tkt
```

If you remove that section and then restart the instance, users will not be able to login into the website. After you add it back, things will be back to normal.